# filebot send duplicates to a new folder and don't overwrite

Tags: python, php, groovy

have a good day today, I bring this filebot script which accommodates the movies by genre, in folders, but I always have many duplicates and when you jump, it leaves them in the source folder since I do not want to overwrite them to the destination.

I would like the duplicates to go to a folder called **DUPLICATES**, but I don't know what to add to it, help and thank you.

```
Z:/Multimedia UNIQedumx/@cinedriveonline/
{
    any
    {
        def order = ['Animation': 1, 'Musical': 2, 'Documentary': 3, 'Family': 4, 'History': 5, 'Science Fiction': 6, 'Horror': 7, 'Fantasy': 8, 'War': 9, 'Western': 10, 'Action': 11, 'Comedy': 12, 'Crime': 13, 'Thriller': 14, 'Adventure': 15, 'Mystery': 16, 'Romance': 17, 'Drama': 18].withDefault{ 100 }
        def map = ['Science Fiction': 'Sci-Fi','Action': 'Acción','Animation': 'Animación','Ciencia ficción': 'Sci-Fi']
        def genres = genres.toSorted{ order[it] }*.replace(map)
        genres.first()
    }
    {
        'No Genre'
    }
}
/{plex.name} - [{vf}] [{mbps}] - @cinedriveonline
```

I should wear something like that

```
{
    ['X:/1st Choice',
     'Y:/2nd Choice',
     'Z:/3rd Choice'
    ].collect{
        // generate file path candidate
        it / plex
    }.find{ 
        // check if file path candidate already exists
        !it.exists()
    }
}
```

but I don't know where to implement it